# webscraper script continuously runs and but with no output/error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webautomation

I am scraping this [site](https://www.adidas.com.sg/release-dates), the data I am trying to **scrape** is the product image, product name, price, and release date.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.adidas.com.sg/release-dates"
productsource = requests.get(url,headers=headers,timeout=15)
productinfo = BeautifulSoup(productsource.text, "lxml")

    #webscraper
for item in productinfo.select(".plc-product-card___1tVAm plc-product-card-mobile___3bmHS"):

    pname = item.find("div", class_='plc-product-name___2cofu gl-product-card__name gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed').get_text(strip=True)                #product title
    price = item.find("div", class_="gl-price-item notranslate gl-label--m").get_text(strip=True)                      #product price
    imagelink = item.find('img')['src']                           #product image link
    plink = f"https://www.adidas.com.sg/{item.a['href']}"                                         #to get product page link
    pdate = item.find("div",class_="gl-price-item notranslate gl-label--m").get_text()


    print(pname,'\n',price,'\n',imagelink,'\n',plink,'\n',pdate)
```

When running this script, it does not return any results or error, terminal is just blank and does not stop running. Not too sure what's the issue here. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Your final call to `get_text` needs parentheses:  `.get_text()`.  As it is, `pdate` is going to be a function, not a string.

Comment: oops I missed it out when copying the code in. Thanks for letting me know I edited it.

Comment: @meliz is this correct `productinfo.select(".plc-product-card___1tVAm plc-product-card-mobile___3bmHS")` please check!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the webpage and the code, you made two mistakes:

1. You were looping through the wrong `<div>`.
2. The syntax used in the find function was wrong.

---

Solution:

```
for item in productinfo.find('div', {'class': 'plc-product-list___1Lg2h'}):
```

```
pdate = item.find("div",class_="gl-price-item notranslate gl-label--m").get_text()
```